# Created vm with virt-manager but it won't boot. Says on bootable device

Tags: kvm-virtualization, aws

I am running dual boot Windows 11 Pro and Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works when I boot to Windows, but I can't set up the VM on ubuntu.

Created vm with virt-manager but it won't boot. Says on bootable device

I used virt-manager to import the vm downloaded from AWS File Gateway but the vm won't boot. It says there is no bootable device. There is a file at /var/lib/libvirt/vm1.qcow2 but I don't know if this is supposed to be the boot device.

I found some guideance at [qcow2 drive not booting](https://groups.google.com/g/kubevirt-dev/c/HX6oG8__59M) but it is talking about BIOS and I checked my BIOS and VMs are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have imported the VM into virt-manager but the boot device is not set correctly. In order to fix this, you can try the following steps:

Open virt-manager and select the VM that is not booting.
Go to the "Overview" tab and click on the "Edit" button.
Go to the "Boot Options" section and make sure that the boot device is set to the correct drive. In your case, it should be set to /var/lib/libvirt/vm1.qcow2.
Click on the "Apply" button to save the changes.
After making these changes, try booting the VM again and see if it works. If you are still having trouble, you may need to troubleshoot the VM further to determine the cause of the problem.